# Singleton of a Winform Application but provide parameters?

Tags: c#, winforms, singleton

I have a webform(c#) application that should only be able to run in a single instance. Its also important that if the applcation is started again(click on app icon) then the new parameters should be forwarded to the current instance but now application are to be started.

I have ofcouse google the problem and found this : http://www.sanity-free.com/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html

This is how I have set it up so far :

```
public class MyApp : ApplicationContext
{
        private static MyApp _instance;
        private static Mutex _mutex = new Mutex(true, "{8F6F0AC4-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-72F04E6BDE8F}");

        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             MyParams params;

             params = ExtractParams(args);

             if (_mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
             {
                  _instance = new MyAppp(params);
                  Application.Run(_instance);
             }
             else
             {
                  _instance.SetParameters(params);
             }
        }
}
```

The problem with this is that the second time I try to start the program I will get an exception in the else that _instance is null?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it's a Inter-process communication (IPC) so _instance doesn't sense. If you want to have IPC, there're some ways to do: socket, namepiped, messaging ...

I think 2 methods are suited:

1. Get the previous process by the process name -> call P/Invoke EnumWindows method to get the main window handle. Send a message with ID has been registered with RegisterWindowMessage before, to pass parameters.
2. Create a namedpipe server to listen for the parameters of the new process.

Comment: I am going with sugestions 2, it seems to work just fine so far.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET assembly `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` contains a class called [WindowsFormsApplicationBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.aspx). This one can also be used by C# applications and has a property called `IsSingleInstance`, which can be set to achieve the required behaviour.

At first application start you can register an event handler for further application starts. From the event args you can extract command line parameters of every additional start.

See an example [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx).

Comment: Stephan > Thanks, I have read about this and we choosed the other way(without the VisualBasic.dll) becouse it did not feelt right to include the VisialBasic.dll file in a c# application? But maby we got no choise anymore?

Comment: +1 nice example, I never spotted that before.  But then again, I've never implemented a single instance app lol

Comment: @SnowJim: Then your approach is a good start and you need to find a way to pass the parameters to the running instance.

Comment: @Stephan > But this example seems be bound to a MainForm? In our case the first form is a login form and its not always that this will be shown. We have infact a MainController(singelton) that handles everything with forms, if I new form are to be opened then the MainController will be contacted. So how does this play with your sugested solution?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you have to make sure that there is always one form set as the MainForm of the Application. The application exits when the MainForm closes. But you can switch the MainForm at runtime.

Comment: This will not be a good soultion in our application, I have tried but it will involve way to much work to get it working. We have multiple forms and sometimes will will not have any form at all.